# TypeError: Cannot read property 'child' of undefined

Tags: javascript, android, google-cloud-functions

I have been researching this but can't seem to find an answer.

I have an app with a rider and a driver.  When the rider requests a ride, it adds the 'history' child to the db.  I also have functions but when this app is executed, the logs cause an error before the 'history' child is added.

index.js :

```js
exports.newRequest = functions.database.ref('/history/{pushId}').onCreate(event => {
    var requestSnapshot = event.data;
    var distance  = requestSnapshot.child('distance').val();
    var price  = distance * 0.5;
    var pushId = event.params.pushId;
    return requestSnapshot.ref.parent.child(pushId).child('price').set(price);
});
```

When I run my app, I get this error in the function logs:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'child' of undefined
at exports.newRequest.functions.database.ref.onCreate.event (/user_code/index.js:17:36)
at cloudFunctionNewSignature (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:105:23)
at cloudFunction (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:135:20)
at /var/tmp/worker/worker.js:733:24
at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)
```

**index.js:17:36**

```
var distance  = requestSnapshot.child('distance').val();
```

My first thought was that the child 'distance' is not available.  In my code, The child 'history' is not added until btnRequest has completed.

Any ideas?  Is there a way to change the code in index.js to work with the code I have in my app?

### Edit #1

After upgrading the API with:

```
npm install firebase-functions@latest --save
npm install firebase-admin@latest --save-exact

npm install -g firebase-tools
```

I updated my index.js file to:

```
exports.newRequest = functions.database.ref('/history/{pushId}').onCreate(snapshot, context => {
var requestSnapshot = snapshot.val();
var distance  = requestSnapshot.child('distance').val();
var price  = distance * 0.5;
var pushId = snapshot.params.pushId;

return requestSnapshot.ref.parent.child(pushId).child('price').set(price);
});
```

Not sure if the above is correct but I deploy and got this response:

```
Error: Error occurred while parsing your function triggers.

ReferenceError: snapshot is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/lizg/Desktop/Programs/Android/Google-Play/ryyde_functions/functions/index.js:15:75)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at /Users/lizg/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/triggerParser.js:21:11
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/lizg/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/triggerParser.js:75:3)
```

### Edit #2

Updated index.js code:

```
exports.newRequest = functions.database.ref('/history/{pushId}').onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
var requestSnapshot = snapshot.val();
var distance  = requestSnapshot.child('distance').val();
var price  = distance * 0.5;
var pushId = snapshot.params.pushId;

return snapshot.ref.parent.child(pushId).child('price').set(price);
```

});

Producing error in logs:

```
TypeError: requestSnapshot.child is not a function
at exports.newRequest.functions.database.ref.onCreate (/user_code/index.js:17:37)
at cloudFunctionNewSignature (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:105:23)
at cloudFunction (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:135:20)
at /var/tmp/worker/worker.js:733:24
at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)
```

index.js:17:37 -  var distance  = requestSnapshot.child('distance').val();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using old APIs against a newer version of the Cloud Functions for Firebase SDK.  You need to update to the new APIs.  In particular, you need to note what changed in version 1.0 of firebase-functions.  [All the changes are summarized here.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff)

In particular, [see what changed in Database triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff#realtime-database).  You're using the old style "event" parameter for the first argument of your database trigger:

```
exports.newRequest =
functions.database.ref('/history/{pushId}').onCreate(event => {
    // ...
})
```

In 1.0, that was changed to accept a [DataSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.database.DataSnapshot) and an [EventContext](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.EventContext#params) object:

```
exports.newRequest =
functions.database.ref('/history/{pushId}').onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
    // ...
})
```

Please see the documentation for more details.

Comment: I have updated my API as suggested and have changed to exports.newRequest =
functions.database.ref('/history/{pushId}').onCreate((snapshot, context) => { ... for the remainder of the code ... I have changed "event" to "snap" but where does context get changed in the code?

Comment: You didn't put parenthesis around the snapshot and context parameters.

Comment: I did as you suggested (snapshot, context) see EDIT #2

Comment: It seems to be working 'somewhat', now to get it to do what I need it to do (will post in another question)  much thanks